# Angular - how to share a controller across modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The module I'm working with currently is copy-pasting code from another module. Obviously this isn't right, so I'm trying to include the shared resource (a module) to obviate this redundancy.

Here's a sketch of the setup:

```
angular.module('shared', []);
angular.module('shared').controller('SharedController', SharedControllerFunc);

function SharedControllerFunc(/*params*/) {
    /*logic*/
}

angular.module('app', ['shared']);
angular.module('app').controller('myController', myControllerFunc);

console.log(angular.module('app').controller('SharedController'));
//looks good!

//HTML template

<div ng-controller="myController">

  <div ng-controller="SharedController" ng-include="other-template.html"></div>

</div>
```

And the SharedController doesn't exist.

**My question is:** How do I get that `SharedController` to resolve correctly? I tried using the `$controller` service and creating `SharedController` on the scope of `MyController`, but it *looks* like it has an issue with transitive dependencies (`Unknown provider` error on `SharedController`).

There has to be a clean, simple way of doing this that I'm overlooking.

Comment: Works OK if you comment out the `console.log` that re-defines the controller to `null`. See the [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efae1hey/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made an example for you here: http://plnkr.co/edit/dBDyYPd3ZoUVdXngu52t?p=preview

If you have 2 files with modules - app and shared:

```
//app.js
var app = angular.module('app', ['shared']);
app.controller('myController', myControllerFunc);

function myControllerFunc($scope) {
  $scope.test = 'myControllerFunc';
   console.log('myControllerFunc called');
}


//shared.js
var shared = angular.module('shared', [])
shared.controller('SharedController', SharedControllerFunc);

function SharedControllerFunc($scope) {
  $scope.test = 'SharedControllerFunc';
   console.log('SharedControllerFunc called');
}
```

Later you can inherit one controller inside the other:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
{{test}}
  <div ng-controller="SharedController">
    {{test}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In principle it works! In my case, it does not. Turns out to be an issue with resolving a dependency. So it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Generally reusing the controllers in `ng-controller` indicates the need for a directive or a service that would perform the common task and keep the codebase DRY. However, the same controller may be reused in several directives or routes.

The listed code is fine. Except this:

```
console.log(angular.module('app').controller('SharedController'));
```

`controller` method is not intended for returning a factory function of registered controller. It is basically equal to overriding the controller with

```
angular.module('app').controller('SharedController', undefined);
```

Comment: I actually didn't know that last bit, because I've never had to doctor code this poorly structured. Thanks!